# Software Updater crashing when installing Ubuntu updates

Tags: updates

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS, and I have been getting prompts to update my software for the last week. Today I accepted the invitation to update, entered my root password, and it started downloading a "Full Upgrade". but after about half an hour (at about 45% progress) I got an error message:

```
Failed to download package files...check your internet connection
```

However, I can ping https://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu without any problems. I tried again twice and got the same error.

So then I opened the Software Updater app and checked for updates. It showed a list of available updates (security, components, applications, etc), so I clicked the Install button. The installation process started, then crashed (the update window closed itself). I tried this again and it crashed again.

I then opened the Software & Updates app, and tried to change the download server from "Main Server" to "Server for United Kingdom". It prompted me for my root password, which I entered, but didn't change the server as requested. I tried this 2-3 times and it still refused to change the download server.

When I tried checking for updates in the same app I got an error:

```
error while refreshing cache...
pk-client-error-quark: could not do untrusted question as no klass support (8)
```

Any idea how I can get the update to work???

Comment: Try opening a terminal, type `sudo apt update`, enter your password. If any errors are reported, copy the full output into your question (copy and paste, not a screenshot). Do the same thing with `sudo apt upgrade`.

Comment: Both of those two commands seemed to complete without error. I got a few "configured multiple times" warning messages for the update, and "function not found" messages for the upgrade, but nothing more serious. So presumably I'm now upgraded, but still have no idea why it wouldn't complete when I tried responding to the original prompts?

Comment: "Configured multiple times" means there are duplicate lines in your sources list. I have never heard of the "function not found" message. I again suggest you copy the full output into your question.